# Questions about the proof of Künneth formula

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry

In the book Principle of Algebra Geometry written by Griffiths and Harris (pages 103-105), they want to prove Künneth formula by harmonic form.

First, they define a map $\varphi$ from$A^{p,q}(M) \otimes A^{r,s}(N)$ to $A^{u,v}(M \times N) :(\zeta(z),\tau(w)) \rightarrow \zeta(z) \wedge \tau(w)$. Here $M,N$ are the complex manifolds; $z,w $the local coordinate of $M,N$ and $p+r=u，q+s=v$.

Then they prove a lemma that ${\varphi(\zeta(z),\tau(w))}$ is $L_{2}$-dense in$A^{u,v}(M \times N)$. Here the inner product is the inner product of differential form.

Later they claim the following properties:

1. $\Delta_{M\times N}=\Delta_{M}+\Delta_{N}$.
2. Choose a complete set ${\eta_{i}}$ the eigenform of $\Delta_{M}$ ,and a complete set${\psi_{i}}$ the eigenform of $\Delta_{N}$,then${\varphi(\eta_{i},\psi_{j}）}$ also a complete set due to the lemma.
3. $\Delta_{M \times N}\varphi(\eta_{i},\psi_{j}=0\Leftrightarrow \Delta_{M}\eta_{i}=0 $and $\Delta_{N}\psi_{j}=0 $ since all eigenvalue$\geq 0$.

**My questions are:**

1. Why is ${\varphi(\eta_{i},\psi_{j}）}$ complete, how to use the lemma to prove it?
2. Why is the eigenvalue all$ \geq 0$.
3. How to conclude the result by using these materials?

Thank you for your answer!